# Continuously playing sound even when screen is locked

Tags: android, audio, lockscreen

Is there any simple way to force my app to continuously play music or a sound, even when the screen is locked?

Comment: You mean - you're playing a music and when screen is being locked, it stops?

Comment: Piotr: Yes, I mean exactly this

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably want to implement a part of your code as a service.  The service will continue to run in the background.  You can easily start and stop the service from your Activity.

Note: Services may be stopped by the Android OS at any point, but they have a higher priority than standard applications, so this is less likely to happen.

There's a tutorial here: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html which does almost exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

override onStop() method in your activity and play your music in it

Comment: It's not the answer for his question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure if the screen is locked that means your activity is in pause mode it will not affect media player instance but if your activity is destroyed and your instance of media player is in that activity - that may stop the player. In this case you have to create a background service which will hold the instance of media played and play sounds in background like media players.